# How to find an inverse of a nearly singular matrix?

Tags: c++, matlab, math, matrix

I am realizing an algorithm using C++ and CUDA. But I got into trouble when I tried to find an inverse of a special matrix.
This matrix has following features:

1. it is a square matrix (suppose: (m+3)x(m+3),m>0);
2. its transpose matrix is its self;
3. its main diagonal must be zeros;
4. it must have a 3x3 zero matrix on the bottom right corner;
5. you can consider this matrix in this form:H = [A ,B ;B' ,0];

I have tried some methods but all failed:

1. **pseudo-inverse matrix:**

   I used matlab at first and got error or warning when I tried to use inv(H'*H):         ***Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision*** or ***matrix is close to singular or badly scaled***
2. **some approximation methods:**

   the reference material is here:[approximation](http://hgpu.org/?p=6093) I found two methods:Gauss-Jordan elimination and Cholesky decomposition.when I tried chol in matlab, i get following ***error:Matrix must be positive definite***

can anybody give me some suggestions?

Comment: By "pseudo-inverse" are you referring to the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse as calculated by `pinv`? I'm not sure what you're doing with `inv(H'*H)` but it doesn't seem like a pseudoinverse.

Comment: @horchler,I just follow the instructions of pseudo-inverse matrix:1.get the transpose:H';2.matrix multiplication:H'*H;3.calculate inverse of new matrix: inv(H'*H); 4.get the pseudo-inverse matrix of H: inv(H'*H)*H'

Comment: @horchler,I tried pinv() to get the inverse matrix: H_inv, but it is strange that H*H_inv is not an identity matrix. this is just one step of my algorithm. so, using something like pinv() may give me potential bugs....

Comment: Ok. That's the naive way of calculating it and the warning is expected. Normally `svd` is used – type `edit pinv` to see the code used. The whole point of a pseudoinverse is that it's not a true inverse (it's used when one cannot be obtained) so you should not expect `H*pinv(H)` to be the identity matrix. Rather, as per the documentation and the definition: `H*pinv(H)*H` equals `H` and `pinv(H)*H*pinv(H)` equals `pinv(H)`.

Comment: @oilpig I suspect that your matrices are structurally singular in which case you cannot invert them. I failed to find a proof though...

Comment: Do you have more details about your matrix?  I can come up with singular or nonsingular matrices that satisfy the requirements.  But `m<3` would make the matrix singular, I think.

Comment: @Teepeemm, actually, these are all the restrictions of my matrix. I want to find a general method to get the inverse of it no matter it is singular or nonsingular...

Comment: But you can't take the inverse of a singular matrix (it's a `1/0` thing).  You can find a [generalized inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) (aka pseudoinverse), but you won't be able to get `H*H_inv=I`: the determinant of the right is `1`, but the determinant of the left is `det(H)*det(H_inv)=0*det(H_inv)=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be good to know some more information on your specific problem and, in particular, if you need the inverse *per se* or if you need to just invert a linear system of equations. I will try to give you directions for both the cases.

Let me start from the consideration that that your matrix is nearly singular and so your system is ill-conditioned.

**DETERMINING THE INVERSE OF A NEARLY SINGULAR MATRIX**

As it has been clarified in the comments and answers above, seeking the inverse of a nearly singular matrix is meaningless. What makes sense is to construct a *regularized* inverse of your matrix. You can do that by resorting to the spectral decomposition (Singular Value Decomposition, or SVD) of your matrix. More in detail, you can construct the singular system, remove the least significant singular values which are the source for the nearly singular behavior of the matrix, and then use the singular values and vectors to form an approximate inverse. Of course, in this case `A*A_inv` will only give an approximation of the identity matrix.

How can this be done on GPU? First, let me say that implementing an SVD algorithm in C++ or CUDA is by no means an easy task. There are several techniques among which you should choose depending on the accuracy you need, for example, to determine the singular values. Anyway, Matlab has a set of [linear algebra functions working on GPU](http://www.mathworks.it/discovery/matlab-gpu.html). Also, [CULA](http://www.culatools.com/) and [Magma](http://icl.cs.utk.edu/magma/) are two libraries offering SVD calculation routines. Also, you can consider using [Arrayfire](http://www.accelereyes.com/products/arrayfire) which also offers linear algebra routines, including the SVD.

**INVERTING A NEARLY SINGULAR SYSTEM**

In this case, you should consider using some sort of Tikhonov regularization, which consists to formulating the inversion of the linear system as an optimization problem and adding a regularization term, which may depend on the features you already know about your uknowns.

For both the cases above, I recommend reading some theory. The book

[M. Bertero, P. Boccacci, Introduction to Inverse Problems in Imaging](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0750304359)

would be useful either if you have to find an approximate inverse or if you have the explicitly invert the linear system.

Comment: thanks a lot, i know that opencv has its own function to calculate pseudo inverse matrix: cv::invert. so, can you tell me which one is better? inverse my matrix in c++ using opencv or follow the original way in GPU using its libraries about SVD?

Comment: @oilpig Have you tried `cv::invert`? As I mentioned above, the fact that your matrix is nearly singular means that it is not invertible. Probably, you will receive a meaningless result if you brutally use `cv::invert`, for the same reason why Matlab's `pinv` doesn't provide you an answer. I think you should try to build up your own _regularized_ inverse by using the singular system of your matrix, filtering the singular values.

Comment: sorry,it makes me confused that the reason that `pinv` or `cv::invert`exits is to invert some nearly singular matrix? So, why do I have to build my own regularized inverse from beginning? Just as horchler said, `pinv` also uses SVD.

Comment: @oilpig Sorry. There is a misprint in my above comment. I meant to mention `inv`. Anyway, you mentioned that you would like to do it in C++ and CUDA and there is no function equivalent to `pinv` in those languages, AFAIK. So, I expect that you should build up your own "`pinv`s" under those languages.

Answer (score 0):

The pseudo-inverse matrix is `inv(H'*H)*H'`, since the condition number of `H` is very high (try `cond(H)`), you may need a regularization factor to obtain the pseudo-inverse matrix: `inv(H'*H + lambda*eye(size(H)))*H'`. The smaller the `lambda`, the lower bias such estimation will achieve. But too small value of `lambda` will lead to high variance (ill-conditioned). You may try a best-suit value.

You can of course use `pinv(H)` directly. The reason why `pinv(H)*H ~= eye(size(H))` is because `pinv(H)` is just an approximation of the inverse of a matrix `H` with the rank lower than `size(H,1)`. In other words, the columns in `H` is not completely independent.

I would like to show you a very simple example:

```
>>a =

     0     1     0
     0     0     1
     0     1     0

  pinv(a) * a
>>
   ans =

     0         0         0
     0    1.0000         0
     0         0    1.0000
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
>>a =  
     1     0
     0     1
     1     0

 pinv(a) * a
>>

 ans =

1.0000         0
     0    1.0000
```

Note `a * pinv(a)` is not identity matrix, because columns of `a` are linearly independent, not the row of `a`. Check this [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Vectors) for more details.

Comment: I want to realize the whole procedure using c++ and cuda. When i type 'edit pinv' in matlab, i know that it uses SVD(), but it is a built-in function, and i can not see the details. So, do you have any ideas how  to realize this function using c++?

Comment: yeah, your material is helpful!