# Polynomial fitting with equal number of data points and coefficients

Tags: python, regression, curve-fitting, polynomials, data-fitting

I am currently experimenting with polynomial fitting using jupyter. The function below returns the least-square polynomial of degree m given the data points in xs with corresponding ys.

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def findas(m,xs,ys):
    A = array([[0]*(m+1)]*(m+1))
    b = array([0]*(m+1))
    for k in range(m+1):
        b[k] = sum(ys*xs**k)
        for i in range(m+1):
            A[k,i] = sum(xs**(k+i))
    coefs = linalg.solve(A,b)
    print(coefs)
    def fit(x):
        return sum(coefs*(x**array(range(len(coefs)))))
    return fit
```

Suppose I have the following six data points and fit a polynomial of degree 5:

```
xs = array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
ys = array([-5.21659 ,2.53152 ,2.05687 ,14.1135 ,20.9673 ,33.5652])
ft = findas(5,xs,ys)
```

From my understanding, the resulting curve should pass through every single data point exactly (in fact, the Lagrange polynomial should be the result).

```
xdense = arange(1,6.1,0.1)
ydense = [ft(x) for x in xdense]   

plt.plot(xdense,ydense)
plt.plot(xs,ys,'rx')
plt.show()
```

Sample output:

[image]

However, this is not the case. The curve is quite far off! What is going on here? Does this have something to do with round-off error? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Mr.T is it better now? Sorry, don't use this much.

Comment: @Mr.T I'm really sorry! I just noticed that all idents disappeared when pasting the code! Yes, I'm using numpy and I've made the edits above.

Comment: This is very likely to a local minimum in chi^2...fitting is local optimization not global optimization

Comment: @mikuszefski that makes sense. Suppose the "real" function behind the sample points was f(x) = 3x+2 and suppose the number of sample points is n and the degree of the regression polynomial is N. If n=N>=1, could such local-but-not-global minima still occur for some N?

Comment: Wait...I got confused a bit. this is fully linear, so the worst case could be higher order than points in which case the problem is badly conditioned.

Comment: maybe you want to look at [SVD](https://www2.math.uconn.edu/~leykekhman/courses/MATH3795/Lectures/Lecture_9_Linear_least_squares_SVD.pdf)

Comment: @mikuszefski sorry, I actually meant n+1 is the number of points, N the degree (with N+1 coefficients). Say we have six points and a fifth-degree polynomial fit. How does full linearity of the sample points prevent a scenario like the one above?

Comment: btw...`np.polyfit` does it nicely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there was a truncation error! The block of code

```
A = array([[0]*(m+1)]*(m+1))
b = array([0]*(m+1))
for k in range(m+1):
...
```

should read:

```
A = array([[0.]*(m+1)]*(m+1))
b = array([0.]*(m+1))
for k in range(m+1):
...
```

i.e we have to specify the zeros as float.

Moreover, round-off errors can amplify in the process of inverting a matrix. This will particularly be the case when the eigenvalues of the matrix that we want to invert differ significantly in their order of magnitude.

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears correct; you re-discovered the issues with trying to invert nearly-singular matrices with finite-precision arithmetic. The matrix A looks like this

```
[[       6       21       91      441     2275    12201]
 [      21       91      441     2275    12201    67171]
 [      91      441     2275    12201    67171   376761]
 [     441     2275    12201    67171   376761  2142595]
 [    2275    12201    67171   376761  2142595 12313161]
 [   12201    67171   376761  2142595 12313161 71340451]]
```

Note how big the difference is between the largest and the smallest value. Its eigevalues are given by

```
[7.35326515e+07 1.98781177e+04 5.75757797e+01 1.74921341e+00
 5.89932892e-02 1.37532926e-04]
```

note the ratio of the largest to the smallest is about 10^11. So the matrix is not singular in the theoretical sense but pretty much singular for numerical calculations. Its inversion leads to extremely large round-off errors, just like dividing by very small numbers would, massively losing precision in the final result.

Lots more detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233414/why-are-there-large-coefficents-for-higher-order-polynomial) and associated links

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! I just got to know that when I put `A = array([[0.]*(m+1)]*(m+1)), b = array([0.]*(m+1))`... with 0. and not just 0 it seems to work fine!

Comment: oh that's interesting. The gist of what I said remains true but the extra twist here is that the calculation was performed in integers instead of floats which have much lower precision, so these issues I described manifested earlier. It was wondering actually why you were having these problems with just 6 points. You may want to write it up as your own answer so it is easier for others to find it

Comment: Hmmm. The Runge, was new for me, but following the link in the link, it states that it is similar to Gibb's phenomenon, which has nothing to do with rounding errors but is a fundamental inherent property. Searching for possibilities to [invert nearly singular matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20931334/803359) I got basically back to the SVD I mentioned above.